# merge all scroll handlers to one from all components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue CLI and I have these components that has a scroll event on mounted property

comp1.vue

```
export default{
    data(){
        showSearchBar : 0
    },
    mounted(){
        const _self = this;
        document.querySelectorAll('.page__content').forEach(function(el){
            el.onscroll = function() {
                if (el.scrollTop >= 200) {
                    _self.showSearchBar = 1;
                }else{
                    _self.showSearchBar = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

comp2.vue

```
export default{
    data(){
        showUsersList : 0
    },
    mounted(){
        const _self = this;
        document.querySelectorAll('.page__content').forEach(function(el){
            el.onscroll = function() {
                if (el.scrollTop >= 200) {
                    _self.showUsersList = 1;
                }else{
                    _self.showUsersList = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I know only one event declaration will work if so happens I have multiple scroll handlers on single page, then I have to group them down to a single scroll event so my question is, how do I merge those handlers into one scroll event so to make all of them work? is there a way on this in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you could do this, is by including the logic inside your `app.vue`, where you also load your `<router-view>` tag:

We then pass the prop down to the individual pages, where we can use it:

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="page__content">
        <router-view :scrolled="scrolled"/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        scrolled: false
    },
    mounted(){
        // Its better use a vue ref here
        document.querySelectorAll('.page__content').forEach((el) => {
            el.onscroll = () => {
                if (el.scrollTop >= 200) {
                    this.scrolled = true;
                } else {
                    this.scrolled = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
</script>
```

**comp2.vue**

```js
export default{
    props: {
        scrolled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        showUsersList() {
            if(this.scrolled) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        },
    },
    mounted(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using router at all, my app built using Onsen ui https://onsen.io so those components are child components of a root vue (app) so in root vue i just do components : { comp1, comp2}